# Serialize run-time created type

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, reflection.emit

I have created a type with `System.Reflection.Emit` following [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.aspx)

I create my type and an instance with this code :

```
//following the tutorial I created a method which returns a dynamic type
Type myDynamicType = CreateNewObject("MyDynamicType", fields);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(myDynamicType);
```

now I want to seralize my object with `XmlSerializer`

tried this :

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Test\SerializedDynamic.XML", FileMode.Create);            
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(object));
xs.Serialize(fs, instance);
```

but it throws an exception :

```
"The type MyDynamicType was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."
```

Any help ?

Comment: have you tried casting?, or this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/e5aakyae.aspx

Comment: What happens if you do: `XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(myDynamicType);` ?

Comment: Can you do what it says you to do? Is it possible to add attributes to your dynamic type? Mainly `[XmlInclude]` which should tell what data type it is. However I think what problem is indeed what @JonEgerton found - you have to provide a type to serializer (could also try `new XmlSerializer(instance.GetType())` if you are passing instance as a parameter into method what performs serialization)

Comment: It worked. I don't know why I forgot to cast ! must get a coffee NOW ! thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on the comment:

I think the issue is that you're creating the `XmlSerializer` with `typeof(object)`.

If you  use either of the following it should work:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(myDynamicType);
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(instance.GetType());
```